# Is it "in" or "on" the dark side?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on

What's the correct word to use, is it "in" or "on" the dark side?  For example:

> Sometimes it's good to be in/on the dark side.

Comment: In popular culture it is almost always "[on the dark side](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tshV-ZyEJpw)." There are cases where you might mean **in** but those are rare and would have specific application.

Comment: Right? I also used this as a play on the Star Wars thing, but I was afraid I'll be questioned at school if it should be "in" since "on" sounded a bit awkward. So I asked here to be sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using *side* in relation to an implicit dichotomy, to place something in one camp rather than in the other camp, as is the case here, then *on* is the preposition to use. We say "*on my side*", "*on the side of the angels*", etc.